# Problems with SQL Server login process C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have an app that uses local SQL Server database with this connection string:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder strCon = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB",
    InitialCatalog = "SQLDB",
    IntegratedSecurity = false,
    UserID = "Sithis",
    Password = "123"
};
```

When I'm trying to start the app I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "A connection was successfully
> established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
> login process. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0"

When I'm using Windows but with `IntegratedSecurity = true`, I get a different error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Cannot open database "SQLDB"
> requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-EGRL9H5\Sithis'."

I don't understand what is happening?

Comment: you either login with windows or with username and password created in sql for that particular database. So if IntegratedSecurity  true, you do not need to put username and password, as it will use your windows password to access, other wise if you make it true, than you need to create Sithis as username and 123 as password in sql management

Comment: If you are logging in with Windows Authentication then set `IntegratedSecurity` to `true` and do not send `Username` and `Password`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it up which kind of Authentication to use.

Either login using

- Windows => IntegratedSecurity = true
- or Username and password => IntegratedSecurity = false

This means when you use Windows, it will automatically use your windows authentication to access the database. And here you should not put username and password.

You can also create a username and password to a specific database or use sa (super administrator) username to access all databases.

If you manage to create a username and password, you find a lot of online resources and guidance on how to do that.